# React Native - Why does the error only come out when the button is click when i assign the textInput to onchange?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, authentication, redux

I have some problem encounter while doing some project.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import {StyleSheet,Text,View,TextInput, 
TouchableOpacity,Keyboard,KeyboardAvoidingView,Image} from "react-native";
import {reduxForm,Field} from "redux-form";

const validate = values =>{
const errors = {};
emailform = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/i
if(!values.email){
    errors.email="not correct format for email address"
}else
    if(!emailform.test(values.email)){
        errors.email="not correct format for email address"
    }

if(!values.password){
    errors.password="please use at least 6 - 12 characters"
}else
    if(values.password.length < 6 || values.password.length > 12){
        errors.password="please use at least 6 - 12 characters"
    }

return errors;
}

const myField = ({label, placeholder ,meta:{error, touched}, input:{onChange}}) =>{
return(
    <View>
    <Text style={styles.inputlabel}> {(label)} </Text>
      <TextInput 
        style={styles.input}
        onChangeText={onChange}
      />
      {touched && (error && (<Text style={styles.errormessage}>{error}</Text>))}
    </View>
);
}

const submit = values =>{
alert('Login Success!');
}

const myFormCom = props=>{
const {handleSubmit, invalid} = props;
return(

    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
      <Image 
        style={styles.logo}
        source={require('./src/images/Logo.png')}
        />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.formContainer}>

    <Field
        name="email"
        component={myField}
        label="Email"
    />

     <Field
        name="password"
        component={myField}
        label="Password"
    />

      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={styles.buttonContainer}
        onPress={handleSubmit(submit)}
        //disabled={invalid}
        >
          <Text 
            style={styles.btnLabel}> 
              Sign In 
          </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  )
}

const LoginForm = reduxForm({
form: 'something',
validate
})(myFormCom);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#faf8ff',
},
logoContainer:{
flexGrow: 1,
alignItems: 'center',
marginTop: 80,
},
logo:{
height: 100
},
formContainer:{
marginBottom: 30
},
input:{
height: 40,
backgroundColor: '#faf8ff',
marginLeft: 20,
marginRight: 20,
paddingLeft: 10,
borderWidth: 2,
borderColor: '#9d81d0',
borderRadius: 5
},
inputlabel:{
marginLeft: 20,
fontSize: 16,
fontWeight: '500',
marginBottom: 4
},
buttonContainer:{
backgroundColor: '#704db2',
marginLeft: 20,
marginRight: 20,
alignItems: 'center',
borderRadius: 5,
marginTop: 15
},
btnLabel:{
fontSize: 20,
color: '#fff',
fontWeight: 'bold',
padding: 10,

},
errormessage: {
color: 'red',
marginLeft: 20,
fontSize:14
}
});

export default LoginForm;
```

All I want is the button would be disable if their are some errors occur but my errors can't be shown when the button is not click. How is that? can someone explain to me? Sorry I'm not quite good in react native and JavaScript; I'm still learning my thing haha

Btw, in myField I declare there that it is onChange in the textInput so that will be change if the text is change right? but why does my error only show when i hit the sign in button? how do i get this thing right to show the error even if the button is not click yet.

Comment: doesnt handleSubmit have to be a function and not a prop? look at this example https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-touches

Comment: my main problem here is that the button needs to be clicked first before the error shows up even the field is onChange